# Android - Extend onGroupClick (ExpandableListView)

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

How can I extend the `onGroupClick` method of an `ExpandableListView` widget. The code I'm currently using overrides the functionality of the original method - how can I extend it?

Code:

```
//expandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(parentClickListener);

...

/*
private OnGroupClickListener parentClickListener = new OnGroupClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) 
    {
        ....
        return true;
    }

};
*/
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try to implement that... `The method onGroupClick(ExpandableListView, View, int, long) is undefined for the type Object`

Comment: I tried to call the superclass but was given the error stated in the comment above. Are you sure about the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

By extending the functionality I assume you want that in addition to expanding the group you should be able to do something extra.
Try the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
    parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Hey there!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}
```

The expandGroup function expands the group for you. However, you now have to manage the collapse event of the group yourself. Use the parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition) method.